# DocuSign callback after user signs a document

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any callback DocuSign is posting in background so I know whether user signed specific document or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can setup webhooks with DocuSign, you can use DocuSign Connect module, or the `eventNotification` object in the envelope definition to configure the callback URL etc.

You can also poll the DocuSign platform asking for the status of specific envelopes, however, there are hourly API rate limits in place so you should avoid polling when possible.

See the [Status and Events](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/status_and_events.html) page in API Docs for more info on these 3 methods.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The above link is outdated. I've searched the docs and haven't figured out where this information lives now.